# Django - sending data with redirect

Tags: python, django

I am sending sending database objects with my home view as follow:

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    questions = list(Question.objects.filter(cat=102))
    random.shuffle(questions)
    context = {'questions': questions[:10]}

    return render(request, 'learning/home.html', context)


def draw_question(request):
    return redirect('home')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('draw_question/', views.draw_question, name='draw_question')
]
```

But I would like to this the other way round.
I would like to load empty home page with button to draw question only.
After that I would like to load data my filtered data with 'draw_question' view and then redirect to my home page with this random values.

Does anyone know how to obtain this?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you forcing yourself to redirect requests? You can do it inside the `home.html`.

I mean something like this:

**views.py**

```py
def home(request):
    context = {'questions': None}
    return render(request, 'learning/home.html', context)


def draw_question(request):
    questions = list(Question.objects.filter(cat=102))
    random.shuffle(questions)
    context = {'questions': questions[:10]}

    return render(request, 'learning/home.html', context)
```

**home.html**

```
{% if questions %}
    load questions
{% else %}
    show the button
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by adding the question ids as query parameter?

```
def home(request):
    context = {}

    if 'questions' in request.GET:
        # Read ids from query parameter and convert to integers
        ids = [int(value) for value in request.GET['questions'].split(',')]
        # Find the matching questions
        questions = Question.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
        # To restore the exact order, make a lookup dictionary
        by_id = {question.id: question for question in questions}
        # Add questions in given order to context
        context['questions'] = [by_id[id_] for id_ in ids]

    return render(request, 'learning/home.html', context)


def draw_question(request):
    # Instead of getting actual questions, only get a list of their ids
    questions = Question.objects.filter(cat=102).values_list('id', flat=True)
    # Randomize the ids
    random.shuffle(questions)
    # Return to home and send a selection of ids as query parameters
    return redirect('home?questions=' + ','.join(questions[:10]))
```